# Enviar formato correctamente por Get | Error

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, get, http-get

Tengo que enviar parámetros por GET pero en este formato

> ?status=2&sales_price=US%240+-+US%24300%2C000&rental_price=US%240+-+US%242%2C000&submit=Search

No tengo ningun problema con los precios sino con **+-+** ya que aparece **%2B-%2B** entonces me da error como puedo solucionarlo para que quede del formato correcto pero al final me sale

> ?status=2&sales_price=US%240%2B-%2BUS%24300%2C000&rental_price=US%240%2B-%2BUS%242%2C000&submit=Search

El formato del range en el input es 1,20000 por lo que realizo un split para cambiarle el formato ademas de agregarle **+-+**

Lo intente con jquery

```
var rent = $("#rental_price").val();
var split_rent = rent.split(",");
$("#rental_price").val(String("US$"+split_rent[0]+"+-+"+"US$"+split_rent[1]));
```

Answer (score 0):

Ya solucione el problema que tenia.

Les dejo la Respuesta

> function o(e){var t=parseInt(e);return t.toLocaleString("en-US")}